# Creating a New Solution from already existing project from GitHub

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have a project on Github repository named "CreditFac" that has been in use by a client.

I want to use the same project but with additional features for another client entirely. I want this new one too to be on github. How do i do this? I have tried cloning but seems not getting it.

I want the projects to have be independent of each other. I do not want to use Branch as it will still be merged by the Master.

Comment: Why is cloning not working?  Do you want it to be in a different GitHub repo?

Comment: Found a way around it. Had to create a local copy on my system and the deleted the .git folder

Answer (score 0):

Found a way out for it.

I created a local copy into a different folder. I then enabled show hidden folders which made me to see the .git folder, I deleted the .git folder and the project loaded successfully without any git attached to it.

I will be creating a different repo for this on my GitHub account.

Thank you..